# how does one call a saga from within another saga?

Tags: redux-saga, react-server

When using redux-connect (the @asynConnect attribute) how does one chain a second saga, that is dependent on a successful completion of the first saga?

Just simply `putting` the saga dispatch action in at the appropriate location in the first saga works on the client, but not on the server.

Comment: I was having the same struggle. I just found this, it saved my job : https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/984

Answer (score 17):

Calling a saga from another saga is as simply as doing a [call](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#callfn-args) effect.

```
yield call(firstSaga, params);
```

For example:

```
yield call(firstSaga);

//do something in current saga with whatever you save
//from the first saga in redux store

const data = select(firstSagaSelector);

yield call(myApi, data);
```